# Android Studio. Image Assets sizes generation

Tags: android, image, assets

I successfully generated a "Launcher Icon" for my project with all expected sizes, now I want to do the same with images to use in ImageViews. I tried all the options in "Image Assets" and none worked.

How can I generate all the different image sizes with Android Studio at once? Just like the launcher icon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you use AndroidStudio this plugin is perfect
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658?pr=